# Multithreading in spring boot controller

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, spring-boot, callable

Following is the code in one of my spring controller.In this I need to store some data in postgres database with multithreading so I don't have wait until it saves data into database and I can send response back to called API.How can I achieve this?

```
//billingLogService.saveBillingLogDetails(Object);
if (!Util.isNull(personId) && !Util.isNull(personConnectionData)) {
    return new Callable<Map<Long, PersonConnectionTo>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<Long, PersonConnectionTo> call() throws Exception {
            Map<Long, PersonConnectionTo> connectionTextMap =
                profileService.getconnectionTextForFocusCompany(focusCompanyId, personId, personConnectionData);
            return connectionTextMap;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You could look at using Spring's `@Async` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to do is put the whole logic(which you want to run in a separate thread) into a method of some service class.
Then
 1. Annotate class with `@Service` or equivalent.
 2. Annotate method with `@Async`
 3.  Use `@EnableAsync`
 That should suffice

Comment: Getting an exception  WARN 9071 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
ERROR 9071 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 123
ERROR 9071 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void com.equilar.bsp.service.impl.BillingLogServiceImpl.saveConnectionText(java.lang.Long)'.

Comment: This is someting related to your code, ant exactly related to running in a separate thread